# Assign each array element attribute with a value from another array respectively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am trying to assign each person an age value from a list with same size.

```
class Person
 attr_accessor :age
end

a = [person1, person2, person3, person4, person5]
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How can I do the assignment below using a neat way(without using index i)?

```
i = 0
a.each do |p|
  p.age = b[i]
  i += 1
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are guaranteed to be the same length, then you can use `zip`:

```
a.zip(b).each do |p, age|
  p.age = age
end
```

As @ardavis pointed out, `zip` takes a block so you can remove the `.each`.

I know you asked for a solution without an index, but note that your code can be made neater even with an index. In Ruby, you don't need to define and increment your own index. Instead, you can use `with_index` like so:

```
a.each.with_index do |p, i|
  p.age = b[i]
end
```

Comment: Could remove the `.each`, `zip` takes a block. `a.zip(b) { |a, b| a.age = b }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index` (as each `Person` instance is going to be unique):

```
a.each { |ai| ai.age = b[a.index(ai)] }
```

#### [Demonstration](https://repl.it/NXlg)

P.S. I would go with the approach introduced by ***@ardavis***, using just `zip`:

```
a.zip(b) { |a, b| a.age = b }
```